# Is this structure to create Cassandra tables for Mahout right?

Tags: cassandra, mahout, cassandra-2.0, mahout-recommender

Following [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052321/cassandra-based-mahout-user-friend-recommendations) I would like to know if this instruction are well performed for Cassandra 2.0, according that in this version the CLI and the comparator stuff is deprecated, as show in this [link](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/reference/referenceStorage_r.html).

Table users:
CREATE TABLE users (userID bigint, itemID bigint, value float, PRIMARY KEY (userID, itemID));

Table items:
CREATE TABLE items (itemID bigint, userID bigint, value float, PRIMARY KEY (itemID, userID));

Table userIDs:
CREATE TABLE userIDs (id bigint, userID bigint PRIMARY KEY(id, userID));

Table itemIDs:
CREATE TABLE itemIDs (id bigint, itemID bigint PRIMARY KEY(id, itemID));

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I could verify in this [presentation](http://es.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/nyc-jonathan-ellis-keynote-cassandra-12-20) that the structure proposed for Cassandra Table for Recommenders in Mahout is ok.

In the slides 37 and 38 is an example for the first two, and in the slides 24 and 25 for the last two.

Anyway if anyone could re-confirm this answer could be helpful to be 100% secure.

Thanks!!!